# Neither client-side or server-side (asp.net) imagemap will popup html form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a sprite that when clicked it should open either an htm help file or video, depending on where clicked.
I have tried asp.net image map and client side map, with and without the window.open and also sending to a javascript function.  Nothing works. 
I really don't want to use server side, but I just can't seem to get this working.

```
<div class="divhelp">
  <br />
  <asp:ImageMap  
         ID="ImageMap1"  
         runat="server"  
         ImageUrl="~/images2020/SpriteVideoandHelp.png" 
         Width="70"  
         Height="32"
         HotSpotMode="NotSet">  
        <asp:RectangleHotSpot Target="_self" Top="0" Bottom="32" Left="0" Right="34" AlternateText="Videos" NavigateUrl="openVideoHelp('1')" />  
        <asp:RectangleHotSpot Target="_blank" Top="0" Bottom="32" Left="35" Right="70" AlternateText="Help" NavigateUrl="javascript:window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm', 'Search', 'width=600,height=450,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1')" />  
    </asp:ImageMap>  
  </div>


<a href="#"><img src="images2020/SpriteVideoandHelp.png" alt="Videos and Help Files" width="70" height="32" border="0" usemap="#mapname"/></a><br />
  <map id="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" onclick="javascript:window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm','Search','width=650,height=500,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1')" alt="Videos" coords="0,32,0,34"/>
    <area shape="rect" onclick="javascript:window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm','Search','width=650,height=500,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1')" alt="Help" coords="0,32,35,70" />
</map>


    function openVideoHelp(imgClicked) {

    if (imgClicked == '1') {
        helpfile = window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm', 'Search', 'width=600,height=450,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1');
        return false;
    }
    else {

        helpfile = window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm', 'Search', 'width=600,height=450,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1');
        return false;
    };

};
```

There are several other variations to the above that I have tried with no luck.

What am I doing wrong or is this not possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the server-side imagemap.

All that is wrong with the client-side imagemap is that you have got the width and height for the image switched. It should be `width="32" height="70"`.

Also, the video area has it's co-ordinates mixed up: it should read `<area coords="0,0,32,34"...`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I switched them and the coords you gave me work, but my switching didn't.  The total image size is 70px wide, 32px high. What is the order I should put coords in?

            <area shape="rect" onclick="javascript:window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm','Search','width=650,height=500,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1')" alt="Videos" coords="0,0,32,34"/>
    <area shape="rect" onclick="javascript:window.open('../HelpFiles/Login.htm','Search','width=650,height=500,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,status=1')" alt="Help" coords="0,35, 32,70" />

Comment: For the first use `coords="0,0,32,34"` and for the second use `coords="32,0,70,35"`.

Comment: Thank you.  Finally figured it out.  The help side coordinates are coords="35, 0, 70, 32", x1=left area where hotspot starts, y1=top, x2=total image width (includes all hotspots), y2= Total image height.

I really appreciate your help.  I spent hours trying to figure it out. With your help it was solved in 10 minutes.

Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I use [Firefox](http://firefox.com) with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). When I uploaded the source to my website (and used a placeholder pic), I hovered over the `<area>` tags with Firebug. It highlights the areas, which showed that the first area was 2 x 0 px, and the second area was off the picture. I then changed the coords with Firebug to see which ones worked. (x1,y1,x2,y2).